# Formatting a table using VBA that is being copied to an email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

[image: Messed up Email]

I have been struggling with this issue for awhile now and I would be very grateful for any help offered. So I have the code that is generating an email from an excel file that I have. The issue is that when the email is pasted over the table does not format correctly. I have attached a screenshot of what the output looks like and the code is below.

```vb
Sub Send_Email()

'Updated by Extendoffice 20200119
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim I, J As Long
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xEmailBody As String
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application
    On Error Resume Next
    xAddress = ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address
    Set xRg = Range("A9:E32")
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    For I = 1 To xRg.Rows.Count
        For J = 1 To xRg.Columns.Count
            xEmailBody = xEmailBody & "  " & xRg.Cells(I, J).Value
        Next
        xEmailBody = xEmailBody & vbNewLine
    Next
    xEmailBody = "" & vbLf & vbLf & "" & vbLf & vbLf & xEmailBody & vbNewLine
    With xMailOut
        .Subject = Worksheets("TDN Generator").Range("A6").Value
        .To = ""
        .Body = xEmailBody
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

THIS IS HOW IT PASTES INTO THE EMAIL:

```
  Hello, 
   
  Check it out:        
          
  Trade 2        
  Trade Type  Grant Number  Security Type  Shares Sold  Shares Exercised 
  Sell To Cover  12345  Restricted Stock  200  
  Sell To Cover  12346  Restricted Stock  220  
  Sell To Cover  12347  Restricted Stock  240  
  Sell To Cover  12348  Restricted Stock  260  
  Sell To Cover  12349  Restricted Stock  280
```

I would like them to all be properly aligned in their said columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Space** function to left- or right-pad the values as required.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Dim colwidth(1 To 5) As Integer
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim val As String
    Dim strout As String
    
    ' adjust the column widths as required
    ' you will get an error if the value is
    ' wider than the column width
    colwidth(1) = 13
    colwidth(2) = 12
    colwidth(3) = 16
    colwidth(4) = 12
    colwidth(5) = 16
    
    ' function is in the worksheet module for convenience
    With Me
    
        Set rg = .Range("A1:E6")
        
        For Each row In rg.Rows
        
            ' pad left
            col = 1
            val = row.Cells(1, col)
            strout = val & Space(colwidth(col) - Len(val) + 1)
        
            ' pad right
            col = 2
            val = row.Cells(1, col)
            strout = strout & Space(colwidth(col) - Len(val)) & val & Space(1)
        
            ' pad left
            col = 3
            val = row.Cells(1, col)
            strout = strout & val & Space(colwidth(col) - Len(val) + 1)
        
            ' pad right
            col = 4
            val = row.Cells(1, col)
            strout = strout & Space(colwidth(col) - Len(val)) & val & Space(1)
        
            ' pad left
            col = 5
            val = row.Cells(1, col)
            strout = strout & val & Space(colwidth(col) - Len(val) + 1)
            
            Debug.Print strout
            
        Next row
    
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Data range

[image]

Output

```
Trade Type    Grant Number Security Type     Shares Sold Shares Exercised 
Sell To Cover        12345 Restricted Stock          200                  
Sell To Cover        12346 Restricted Stock          220                  
Sell To Cover        12347 Restricted Stock          240                  
Sell To Cover        12348 Restricted Stock          260                  
Sell To Cover        12349 Restricted Stock          280
```

Of course, this will only work with a fixed pitch typeface. Much better to write the data as an html table if the mail client supports that.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML format:

```vb
Sub Send_Email()

    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim I, J As Long
    Dim xAddress As String
    Dim xEmailBody As String
    Dim xMailOut As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim xOutApp As Outlook.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set xRg = Range("A9:E32")
    xEmailBody = "Take a look:<br><br>" & HtmlTable(xRg)
    
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xMailOut = xOutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    
    With xMailOut
        .Subject = Worksheets("TDN Generator").Range("A6").Value
        .To = ""
        .HTMLBody = xEmailBody
        .Display
        '.Send
    End With
    Set xMailOut = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Function HtmlTable(rng As Range) As String
    Dim s As String, rw As Range, c As Range
    s = "<table border=1>"
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        s = s & "<tr>"
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            s = s & "<td>" & c.Value & "</td>"
        Next c
        s = s & "</tr>"
    Next rw
    HtmlTable = s & "</table>"
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you for the help. I was wondering if this html formatting will work if the number of rows I have in the table fluctuate? Also where would I insert this code into the existing code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's included in the table depends only on the range passed to the function: you can pass any range you want (within reason size-wise)  As for integration - as shown above?  That's pretty much what you have in your question, but the table generation is in a separate function.

Comment: Hi Tim this is super helpful and has got me on the right track. I am wondering two things though. Firstly is it possible to do this with a two varying ranges? So for example sometimes there will be an extra column that will need to be included in that table like "other". The second element that could vary is if things sell at differing prices I want to provide more detail and so at the bottom I would include a date and number. Sometimes this would not need to be included though because they are all the same price. Not sure if this if this is too much to ask. I do really appreciate it though.

Comment: Lastly, is it possible to get the table to look like the one I screenshotted originally?

Comment: Pretty much *anything* is possible but each thing you want to do needs to be coded, so you'll need to try to understand the logic and how it all fits together.  If you want to add styling to the mail then you will need to learn a little about css and how that's used with HTML.  That in itself could be a big topic and not easily covered here.  If you have specific follow-up questions then a new post coving the exact requirements would likely be warranted.

Comment: In order to do the varying range I have this line of code in there:                             `Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select range you need to paste into email body", "KuTools For Excel", xAddress, , , , , 8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`                                                                        
         instead of  Set xRg = Range("A9:E32")

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help Tim! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the paste special command?

It's usually CTRL+ALT+V or ALT+E+S to open the paste special dialog.

Comment: I was unable to get paste special to work. Not sure if it was just how I was doing it or if that will not work with my particular issue.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked, which relates to VBA code. It might make a good comment to the original question if you had the comment privilege, which you do not at this point. This space is reserved for the sole purpose of providing an answer to the question asked above.